# Jquery change variable value onclick

Tags: jquery

I am declaring a variable like this:

```
var list = 0;
```

I then want to change the variable value through a click event.

```
$('div#showList').click(function() { list = 1; });
```

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: you want to increment it on every click or what?please describe briefly..

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Are they in the same scope? Or; do you declare the variable in another function?

Comment: use alert("foo"); in this block. to debug the code may be problem with selector..

Comment: Done friends, I got a work around, don't know why this was not working earlier.